# Update sqlite3 dll in PHP on Windows

Tags: php, sqlite

I run PHP 5.4.16 on Apache on Windows. It uses sqlite3 3.7.7, I'd like to update it to 3.7.11.

Can I just overwrite the php_sqlite3.dll in the ext subdirectory, or do I need to compile PHP?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just replace the library without recompiling.

You will, however, need to restart the web server before PHP will pick up the new library.